# not receiving php mail() messages from remote host

Tags: php

I have a email form [Here](http://keilcarpenter.somee.com/) and am invoking the `mail()` function. for some reason I am not receiving any emails to my email account. My only guess is that it could be some config on the server

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'keilcarpenter01@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

And the html form:

```
          <h1>Contact Form</h1>
                    <p>Send me a message and I will get back to you!</p>
                    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Could it be some config on the remote host or something wrong on my end?

I read that if your sending from localhost then you need to config the php.ini and sendmail.ini so I know that is out of the question.

Would PHPMailer be better to use?

Comment: Have you check your php.ini and what the mail setting there?

Comment: its being sent from remote server so its got nothing to do with my php.ini on my local machine. Not too sure what their mail settings are there. I can only find things to make an email account on their domain